# Search for a non exact match and return column 1 of that file

Tags: text-processing, files, awk, gawk

I have a tab seperated file which looks like this:

```
Adam    Group1,Group2,Group8,Group9,Group10
James   Group1,Group11,Group12,Group7
Kelly   Group18
Alfred  Group1,Group8,Group10
Manuel  Group2,Group5,Group1
Jack    Group11,Group8,Group19
```

I now want to search for a Group, say group 1, and have the return be all members of that group. For example the return for "Group1" would be:

```
Adam
James
Alfred
```

And the return for example Group12 would be:

```
James
```

I'm not sure how to search within a column, without it being an exact match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU Awk:

```
awk '/\<Group1\>/ {print $1}' file
Adam
James
Alfred
Manuel
```

Note: according to your input data, Manuel *is* in Group1...

Comment: Oh sorry, yes he is.

Thank you, this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason the whole word matching (`\<...\>`) is not working with my awk's version, so I had to solve it with `grep`'s help:

`grep '\<Group1\>' filename | awk '{print $1}'`